# Prime numbers proof

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing

My problem:

Prove that a natural number $p$ is prime if and only if $p > 1$ and there exists no natural
number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $1<n\le \sqrt{p}$ such that $n|p$.

Help!

Comment: It just follows from the definition of prime numbers, right?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I think the point is to prove that it's enough to check $n$ with $n \leq \sqrt{p}$, instead of all $n < p$.

Comment: Oh, ok I understand.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is prime then the later statement is obvious. Now, let $p>1$ and $\forall 1<n\le \sqrt{p},\ n\not| p$. If $p$ is not prime, then $\exists\ 1<a\le b<p$ such that $p=ab\implies p\ge a^2\implies a\le \sqrt{p}$ and $a|p$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: theorem- Every composite number has a proper factor less than or equal to its square root.

Suppose n is composite. I can write  $n = ab$ , where $1 < a, b < n$ . If both $a, b > \sqrt{n}$ , then

$$n = \sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt{n} < a\cdot b = n.$$

This contradiction shows that at least one of a, b must be less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$